# Are React, ReactJS and React.js different names for the same thing?

Tags: reactjs

Are **React**, **ReactJS** and **React.js** different names for the same thing?

If they *are* different, what are the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**React = react = react.js = reactjs = ...**

They all refer to the same JS library.

As Mentioned in their website:

> React is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces

From what I know, `.js` and `JS` suffixes are a common thing in JavaScript world. Since `React` is a general world, sometimes they call it `ReactJS` to show it's a JS library.
Other examples are `Next.js`, `Editor.js`, `Express.js`, `Node.js` and so on...

Also you can see the website is [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org), but it's called React in the page.

Answer (score 1):

React is a utility package for UI implementation build by javascript.
So the base name is "react", but you can express its language more specifically by attaching js to it and make it bound to the web.
Also, it makes it distinguishable from other libraries called [ReactNative](https://reactnative.dev/).

There is no package such as react.js or ReactJs on npm and the main package is the "react" itself.

These named you've mentioned, might be for the focus on the core name itself, preventing collision from other packages with react itself

There is [reactphph](https://reactphp.org/) but the react keyword is using as a reference to this [react](https://reactjs.org/) not react in any other language or something.

Comment: There is a react.js on NuGet…

Comment: Wow @BrianTHOMAS,  I didn't know there is something like NuGet.The package you've mentioned didn't receive an update since 2016, It might be the React.core which is the more trusted one ;)